# Strict search and replace text in Python

Tags: python

Let's consider a list as such :

```
listing = ['15.32','25.6','.','12.8','.']
```

What would be the way to search and erase (or replace) the values consisting of a single period (.)? In Python 3 would be best.

EDIT: By "erase" I mean that I want a null value, I need to keep the same lenght of the list.

Comment: Is it a list of strings?

Comment: Please double check your data structures for syntax errors before you post them. This list is not valid Python.

Comment: A single period is not a valid number. you cannot have that list in python. Did you tried that code yourself before posting? You didn't get an error?

Comment: I am sorry, indeed it cannot exists. My list comes from a CSV, so actually it translate in text. I corrected.

Answer (score 2):

```
listing = ['15.32','25.6','.','12.8','.']
listing = [None if a == '.' else a for a in listing]
```

Comment: @knelwood Oh, I expected that `.` should work like `0.` and `.0`. My bad.

Comment: I edited my question: I want to have a null value and keep the same length of the list

Comment: @GuiOmClair here you go

Answer (score 0):

you may try:

```
listing = [i for i in listing if i != '.']
```

Comment: I edited my question: I want to have a null value and keep the same length of the list